# For any linear operator $\phi$ on $V$, prove such an integer $m$ exists.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Suppose $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over some infinite number field $K$, $\phi\in\mathcal L(V)$, prove there exists such a (positive) integer  $m$ that
$$\text{Im} \phi^m=\text{Im} \phi^{m+1},\,\text{Ker}\phi^m=\text{Ker}\phi^{m+1},\,V=\text{Im} \phi^m\oplus \text{Ker} \phi^m$$

Honestly I have no idea where to start. Using matrix representation doesn't help much for me.

Can you help me? Any kind of help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi$ maps each $x$ to $0$ or nonzero, $\dim(\phi^{k+1})\leqslant\dim(\phi^{k})$. If inequalities hold for all $n$, i.e, 
$$
\dim(\phi^{})>\dim(\phi^{2})>\cdots>\dim(\phi^{n})
$$
Then $\dim(\phi^{n})=0$, or $\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{n})=0$ and $\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{n}))=n$. So 
$$
V=\operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{n})=\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{n})\oplus \operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{n})
$$
If for some $m$ such that $\dim(\phi^{m+1})=\dim(\phi^{m})$, then $\phi^{m}$ is invariant under $\phi$. So there is 
$$
\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{m})\cap \operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{m})=\{0\}\tag{1}
$$
for if not, let $x\in \operatorname{Im}(\phi^{m})\cap \operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{m})$, then $\phi(x)=0$ and $\dim(\phi^{m+1})<\dim(\phi^{m})$.

Since $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{m}))+\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{m}))=n$, by $(1)$, $\phi$ can be decomposed into the direct sum of $\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{m})$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{m})$. So
$$
V=\operatorname{Im} (\phi^m)\oplus \operatorname{Ker} (\phi^m)
$$

Comment: But how to show that $\text{Im}\phi^{m+1}=\text{Im}\phi^m$? You only show that there share the same dimension number? I cannot follow  your $\phi^m$ is invariant under $\phi$ argument

Comment: Note $\dim(\phi^{m})=\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{m})$. $\phi^{m}$ is invariant under $\phi$ means that $\phi(\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{m}))=\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{m})$ and $\phi(\operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{m}))=\operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{m})$, which leads to $\operatorname{Im}(\phi^{m})\cap \operatorname{Ker}(\phi^{m})=\{0\}$.

Comment: do you mean $\dim\phi^m=\dim\text{Im}\phi^m$? If so, I'm still not getting how $\phi(\text{Im}\phi^m)=\text{Im}\phi^m$. (I understand the direct sum part, though)

Comment: Yes, $\dim{(ϕ^m)}=\dim{Im(ϕ^m)}$. Suppose $x\in Im(ϕ^m)$ be a base vector. If $ϕ(x)=0$, then $\dim(\phi^{m+1})<\dim(\phi^{m})$.

Comment: I understand this point, sir. But "$\phi^m$ is invariant under $\phi$" eludes me.

Comment: That means image space of $ϕ^m$ is invariant under $ϕ$, or $ϕ(Im(ϕ^m))\subset Im(ϕ^m)$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I know what it means, but I don't know how you have arrived at this point in your answer. Why can it be implied by $\dim im  \phi^m=\dim im  \phi^{m+1}$? I don't find the implication trivial, maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: Suppose $x∈Im(ϕ^m)$ be a base vector. If $ϕ(x)=0$, then the number of base of $Im(ϕ^{(m+1)})$ is less than that of $Im(ϕ^m)$.

Comment: yes they must share the same dimesnsion number, but does it imply they are just *the same subspace*? I don't think it's very clear. What if $\phi(x)$ is nonzero but $\phi(im\phi^m)$ forms a different subspace than $im\phi^m$?

Comment: They are not the same space for they are of different dimension. 2nd question is impossible since $ϕ^m$ is invariant under $ϕ$, or $ϕ(Im(ϕ^m))⊂Im(ϕ^m)$.

Comment: Consider the bases of $Im(ϕ^m)$ under $ϕ$.

Comment: Oh I realised this! Just to see $\phi^{m+1}=\phi^m\cdot \phi$ is sufficient.. Sorry that I was being so stupid. And thanks again for your patience and time!

Comment: $ϕ^{2m+1}=ϕ^{2m}$ is right

Comment: yeah I did vote up..